# How to change the way Maven target directory is created?

Tags: maven, directory, maven-plugin

I am wondering which maven-plugin is responsible of creating the directory `/target` or whatever is configured in the pom.

For some reasons I'd like to change the way this folder is created (link instead of directory).

One other option is to run my own plugin before this target folder is created but I don't know how ensure I'll be the first.

Any idea?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Making a link from the target folder sounds a little bit strange?

Comment: I want to create a target folder that points to my ramdisk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to point your `build` directory to ramdisk, I suggest you do not link to it, but rather use a property that points there, e.g.

```
<properties>
  <custom.build.directory>/path/to/ram/disk/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}</custom.build.directory>
</properties>
<build>
  <directory>${custom.build.directory}</directory>
  ...
</build>
```

I suggest, that you rather put this directives into a custom profile that is only activated on your system.

Comment: This is a standard way but unfortunately it may have a drawbacks. Some badly written build scripts called from Maven, i.e. ant-run, enunciate, etc, may expect that target folder is near `src` dir.
Another reason is that some of your run configurations from IDE may expect that binary is in target.
Also it might be uncomfortable to go away from your sources.

Answer (score 1):

See [DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared/blob/2397c17c54b6abf73d5cf8d443af6d96b5d624d9/maven-filtering/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java#L191) class.
As I understood it creates `target` dynamically from any lifecycle if it needed.
So you can't predict exact time of creation of `outputDirectory`.

But according to [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) "initialize build state, e.g. set properties or create directories." - it should be created on this phase. In my opinion this is a bug and should be reported.

You may try to create any folder with exec or antrun plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>createInMemoryTarget</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <mkdir dir="M:/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}"/>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Where `M:` is your ramdisk.
Then you can mount in with [junction plugin](http://pyx4j.com/pyx4j-maven-plugins/maven-junction-plugin/introduction.html):

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.pyx4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-junction-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>symlinkTargetToInMemory</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>link</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <links>
                            <!-- link the target folder to appropriate in-memory to directory -->
                            <link>
                                <src>M:/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</src>
                                <dst>${project.build.directory}</dst>
                            </link>
                        </links>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Then you may place this config of two plugins to profile and activate it if needed.